# Зачем нужен "loopback interface" в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

> The IP address '127.0.0.1' indicates the IPv4 loopback interface.
>   The IP address '::1' indicates the IPv6 loopback interface. [Источник](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html).

Для чего нужно создавать акканты с такими хостами?

PS В мануале информации не нашёл, но судя по названию "петля взад интерфейс" и [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) это надо для тестирования.

Comment: если у вас клиенты пользующиеся MySQL расположены на той же машине (что довольно часто, для небольших web-проектов) то вам незачем светить MySQL наружу. И тогда вы вешаете его только на лупбаке, он по определению доступен только в переделах машины, получить доступ из вне невозмножно

Comment: @Mike Под "вешаете" вы подразумеваете создание аккаунтов только с хостами: `'127.0.0.1'` и `'::1'`?

Comment: подразумеваю в my.cf выставление bind-address в 127.0.0.1 Но и если у вас есть как внешние пользователи так и внутренние прописывание localhost в именах внутренних пользователей повышает безопастность

Comment: И вообще когда вы знаете, что MySQL у вас же на хосте то обращаться к нему по 127.0.0.1 гораздо удобнее, чем вспоминать какие у него внешние ip, которые к тому же могут поменяться

Comment: @Mike А если в `bind-address` указать внешний IP-адрес севрера вместо `'127.0.0.1'` MySQL будет принимать внешние соединения?

Comment: да, если внешний адрес или 0.0.0.0, обозначающие "любой адрес" то будет конечно

Comment: @Mike Я правильно понимаю, что `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` это всё таки финт, а по-нормальному внешние хосты следует определять в аккаунтах?

Comment: почему финт. это самый надежный способ защиты от подключения из вне, если надо запретить любые подключения из вне. И главное, это обезопасит даже если в MySQL найдется очередная уязвимость, позволяющая подключится без пароля и т.п.

Comment: @Mike Не сомневаюсь что это работает, просто под финтом я имел ввиду неочевидный приём, в мануале `bind-address=127.0.0.1` встречается только один раз в разделе решение проблем с подключением.